# google visualization Query second iteration

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google.visualization.Query to get data from a Google Sheet. I am noticing the result does not include a comma between rows, which is causing an issue because I am trying to create an array. How can I fix this?

```
Rows:
4,1,some text,2/25/2021,3/2/2021 
9,1,some text,2/25/2021,3/1/2021

Query:
        function initialize() {
              var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
              var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, D, F, G WHERE B=1 offset 1');
              var query = new google.visualization.Query(
                  'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jyiF2nZsqkxzSndIaiZEVivFB7EzozHHuE0Qx2hU1T4/gviz/tq?tq=' + queryString);
              query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

Query Result:
4,1,some text,2/25/2021,3/2/2021 9,1,some text,2/25/2021,3/1/2021


    Iterate in an Array:

        dataTable.addRows([  
          [ '+myArray[0]+', <div class="ggl-tooltip">'+myArray[1]+'</div>', myArray[2], myArray[3) ]   
         ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the query's response function, you can get the data from the response argument.

```
function handleQueryResponse(response) {

  var data = response.getDataTable();
```

this will return a [google data table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable), which can then be used to draw a chart.

if you need the raw data in an array, you can use the `toJSON` method.

```
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var rawData = data.toJSON();
```

the json will be returned in the format found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)...

Comment: Thank you for all the help, WhiteHat. Is there a way to manipulate the json data before it is used to draw the chart?

Comment: sure, what is it you want to do? you can modify the data table before using `toJSON`. add rows, change values, anything...

Comment: It would be great to be able to use the content like I'm showing in 'Iterate in an Array:' in the first post.

Comment: sorry, I'm having trouble following. if you could edit one of the questions with the complete code and indicate where you're having issues, I will try to help...

Comment: Whitehat, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387353/google-visulation-json-values